# Create new worksheet for each unique value

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have the following code that does a great job at copying relevant data into my sheets. I create each sheet manually for every unique department in column J, then I run this macro. I would like a macro that creates the sheets dynamically based on unique values within column J. I have found good resources online but the ones I've found seem to error when it reaches a row that has already had a sheet created for it. I have included the code I'm currently using as well as a screenshot of my inventory sheet before I manually create the other worksheets

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim bottomJ As Integer
bottomJ = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each c In Sheets("All Dept.").Range("J2:J" & bottomJ)
    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate
        If ws.Name = c Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next ws
    Next c

End Sub
```

[image: Sample Excel Data]

Comment: What error do you get and on what line of your code?

Comment: Are you saying that for each unique value in column `J` of the worksheet `All Dept.`, you want to create a new worksheet containing the same table but with only the relevant data? Do you want these worksheets copied to the existing workbook or to a new one? If any of the worksheets previously exist, should it be deleted and then again created, or its contents cleared and then the possibly different contents copied or what? Please be more specific and add more detail to your post.

Comment: Your code assumes you need to separate data line by line, but why not take advantage of what Excel already offers?  You could copy the entire table to each sheet, then filter and remove hidden for each sheet.  That may cut down on a significant amount of effort.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. For each unique value within column J of the worksheet All dept I would end up with 4 new sheets. So for the screenshot above, I would end with 4 blank worksheets. The 4 blank worksheets would be named "500 - NETWORK OPERATIONS", "100 - CUSTOMER SERVICE", "300 - ADMIN", and "700-ENGINEERING".

Comment: Hey Cyril, I think that method could work as well and would be much faster, but I would still need a way to dynamically create the sheets/rename them to each unique value in column J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub CreateSheets()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim dic As Object
Dim ky As Variant

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("J2"), .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    For Each cl In rng
        If Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Value
        End If
    Next cl
    
    For Each ky In dic.keys
          Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = dic(ky)
    Next ky
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear this.

Comment: You don't need the reference since you are using a `late-bound` dictionary. If you would want to utilize the created reference, that is `early binding`, you would apply the following changes: `Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary` and `Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

### Create Criteria Worksheets

- The problem with your idea is e.g. that you use the Hafiz Sb's `CreateSheets` procedure to create the worksheets and then you use your `CopyRows` procedure to write the data. Now you add more data to the main worksheet and you're stuck. How will you add the new data to the respective worksheets?
- The following assumes that you will only add, not delete data from the main worksheet.
- It will copy the main worksheet as many times as there are unique values in a column ('scCol') and by using `Autofilter`, will delete the undesired data on each of the worksheets (it is my idea, but something similar (if not the same) was suggested by Cyril in the comments).
- I did something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869853/create-a-new-workbook-for-each-unique-row-in-excel-vba/68870567#68870567), which writes the worksheets to separate workbooks.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CriteriaWorksheetsCreator()
    ' Accompanying procedures:
    '   ArrUniqueColumnRange
    '   DeleteWorksheetsViaArray
    
    Const sName As String = "All Dept."
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const sfRow As Long = 1 ' Header Row
    Const scCol As Long = 10 ' Criteria Column
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = sws.Range(sFirst).CurrentRegion
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only one (header) row
    If rg.Columns.Count < scCol Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    Dim strg As Range
    Set strg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - sfRow + 1).Offset(sfRow - 1)
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sdrg.Columns(scCol)
    
    Dim wsNames As Variant: wsNames = ArrUniqueColumnRange(scrg)
    If IsEmpty(wsNames) Then Exit Sub ' no valid data in 'scrg'
    
    Dim tAddress As String: tAddress = strg.Address
    Dim cAddress As String: cAddress = scrg.Address

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    DeleteWorksheetsViaArray wb, wsNames
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dtrg As Range
    Dim dcrg As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim dName As String
    For n = 0 To UBound(wsNames)
        sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set dws = ActiveSheet
        dName = wsNames(n)
        dws.Name = dName
        Set dtrg = dws.Range(tAddress)
        dtrg.AutoFilter scCol, "<>" & dName
        If Application.Subtotal(103, dtrg.Columns(scCol)) > 1 Then
            Set dcrg = dws.Range(cAddress)
            Set drg = dcrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            drg.Delete
        End If
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next n

    sws.Activate
    'wb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Criteria worksheets created.", _
        vbInformation, "Criteria Worksheets Creator"

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values from the first column of a range,
'               in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrUniqueColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With rg.Columns(1)
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim r As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Key = Data(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    .Item(Key) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next r
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and/or blanks
        ArrUniqueColumnRange = .keys
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Deletes all worksheets whose names are in an array ('wsNames'),
'               from a workbook ('wb').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DeleteWorksheetsViaArray( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal wsNames As Variant)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim LB As Long: LB = LBound(wsNames)
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(wsNames)
    Dim wsnCount As Long: wsnCount = UB - LB + 1
    
    Dim DeleteSheetNames() As String: ReDim DeleteSheetNames(0 To wsnCount - 1)
    
    Dim dn As Long
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sn As Long
    Dim wsName As String
    For sn = LB To UB
        wsName = wsNames(sn)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
                ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
            DeleteSheetNames(dn) = wsName
            dn = dn + 1
            Set ws = Nothing
        End If
    Next sn
    
    If dn = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    If dn < wsnCount Then
        ReDim Preserve DeleteSheetNames(0 To dn - 1)
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Worksheets(DeleteSheetNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Your explanation of adding data to the primary worksheet is true, but not needed. This report is used for inventory and we never add or remove data from the sheet. Every item within our org is captured. This is simply for breaking apart the information by department.